# Degree of a Vertex Problem

Tags: graph-theory

A graph $G$ has the property that every edge of $G$ joins an odd vertex with an even vertex. Show that $G$ is bipartite and has even size.

Comment: so... showing bipartiteness is easy... Right? And the second property is false.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you see how to divide the vertices into two sets to show the graph is bipartite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vertices of [bipartite graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) can be partitioned into two sets $A$ and $B$ for which every edge in the graph is an $A$-to-$B$ edge.

In this case, we know that every vertex is an (odd-degree-vertex)-to-(even-degree-vertex) edge, which should indicate what would be a suitable partition.

By "size", I think this means number of edges (since it's false if it means number of vertices).  Here's a hint: The number of edges in this particular graph is the sum of degrees of the even-degree vertices [why?].